# Eclipse: impossible to load from Git repository

Tags: eclipse, git

I am trying to use Eclipse to connect to GIT repository.

I go to `File -> Import -> Git -> Projects from Git -> Clone URI`...

There I fill everything what is needed. And on the next tab I set the master branch.
I pick the directory, which should be the Local Destination (i.e. C:\Dev\Eclipse_workspace\Automation).
The folder Automation doesn't exist.

On the next screen, I choose *"Import as general project"*.

It tells me *"Project Automation already exists"*.

So I remove the folder.

But then it tells me *"Directory C:\Dev\Eclipse_workspace\Automation does not exist"*.
[image]

Unfortunately, I have to use Eclipse on dedicated computer for this current project and don't have the option to use other IDE.

Can you give me any advice of whether it's a bug, or just some misunderstanding?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work this way because importing here only works if the repository is outside the workspace.

Either select a location outside the workspace or do the following:

1. **Clone** the project into the workspace as you did it, but **without importing**:
    In Quick Access (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>**) type `Clone a Git Repository` to open the *Clone* dialog
2. Create a **new *General Project*** named `Automation`: *File > New > Other...: General > Project*

Comment: ad 1. How can I do it without importing? ad. 2. So I need to create a new General Project to be able to clone an existing one? I don't get the point.

Comment: Clone the Git repository into the workspace as you did it, but without importing the project via in Quick Access (Ctrl+3) typing `Clone a Git Repository` (see my corrected answer). Step 2 is to open the project: creating a project uses an existing directory and does not delete its content. Usually, a Git repository is cloned into `GIT_HOME` directory outside the Eclipse workspace and then imported/mapped into the workspace. But in your unusual case importing seems to fail because the source and the target are the same (you are welcome to contribute a patch for that).